# Magento 2: Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error

Tags: magento2, orders, cron

I'm creating Order export cron module for Magento 2.3. I'm getting below error

```
Cron-job "monthly_report" threw exception InvalidArgumentException    
In Json.php line 39                                              
Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error
```

While debugging, I found below line produces error. I'm retrieving order details using OrderCollection Factory.

```
$order->getAllVisibleItems();
```

I tried below suggestions from stackexchange:

1. redis-cli flushall
2. bin/magento cache:clean

Answer (score 0):

The Error was due to incorrect M2 db. I'm not sure why the DB is not imported properly, though I have used CLI command during each installation.

There were couple of answers in other tickets were issue was due to incorrect M1 db. In my case M2 DB was corrupted. Hope it helps someone.